# SPLIT function in Google Spreadsheets with OR statement

Tags: google-sheets

I want to use the split function, but with different delimiters. I thought of something like this:  `=SPLIT(A:A;OR("-","&"))` but it doesn't work.

*Is it possible to have Boolean statements within a SPLIT function?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The help says:

```
SPLIT(string, delimiter, treat_delimiters_individually)
```

so for text in A1 the function is

```
=SPLIT(A1,"-&",true)
```