# How to use the SPLIT function in Google Spreadsheets with different delimiters and with some delimiters with multiple characters?

Tags: google-sheets

My question is similar to this one:
[SPLIT function in Google Spreadsheets with OR statement](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/39632/split-function-in-google-spreadsheets-with-or-statement)

but has the following difference:

I want to use the delimiter "`apple`" and the delimiter "`.`" within the SPLIT function.

Since the delimiter `apple` has multiple characters, @parkydr answer [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/39639/219739) doesn't work.

**Example:**

On this input on A2:

```
I ate an apple on the bus home. Going
```

I want it to split like this:

```
I ate an / on the bus home / Going
```

I tried this:

```
=SPLIT(A2,"apple.",TRUE)

I / t   /   n   / on / th   / bus / hom / Going
```

and this

```
=SPLIT(A2,"'apple''.'",TRUE)

I / t   /   n   / on / th   / bus / hom / Going
```

and this

```
=SPLIT(A2,"apple.",false)

I ate an apple on the bus home. Going
```

and this

```
=SPLIT(A2,"apple"".",false)
#ERROR Formula parse error.
```

and this

```
=SPLIT(A2,"'apple''.'",false)
I ate an apple on the bus home. Going
```

How to make  return the next split?

```
I ate an / on the bus home / Going
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to [replace](https://regex101.com) all delimiters with a unique delimiter and split.

```
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"apple|\.","✱"),"✱")
```

Comment: Thanks @TheMaster! It's working. Great way to embed the formulas, I'm beginning to see how to use complex embedded formulas as arguments to other complex formulas. Thanks also for the regex101 link, I bookmarked it and will look to see how to make use of it! Just looked at the quick reference and all tokens and it gives great ideas suggestions of what you can do with it.

Comment: I didn't know regular expressions could be used within formulas. Now I understand a previous formula I saw with regexes! In the meantime I found this that explains simply regexes uses in details: [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)  Take care! Talk soon.

Comment: Just found these too to help with regexes! [regexone](https://regexone.com/lesson/wildcards_dot) and  [Regex tutorial](https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285)

Comment: @Lod Great. Keep practising if you're interested.

Comment: I just found this new summary page for regexes quick references: [codexpedia](https://web.archive.org/web/20190630100702/https://www.codexpedia.com/regex/regex-symbol-list-and-regex-examples/) .Saved with the [archive.org extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wayback-machine/fpnmgdkabkmnadcjpehmlllkndpkmiak)

Comment: More great regex resources: [Learning Regular Expressions [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions/2759417#comment100214921_2759417) .                                
                                                                                                                        
And for quick references: [Quick-Start: Regex Cheat Sheet](https://web.archive.org/web/20190701071457/https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html)