# Split Text to columns in Google Sheets with multiple full words as delimiters - "to" or "for"

Tags: google-sheets

I need to split a text when the delimiter is "on" or "to" or even "for", removing the delimiter from the results:

Ex:
Creating more value **for** business =
Creating more value / business

Creating more value **to** people =
Creating more value / people

Creating more value **on** businesses =
Creating more value / business

I looked into [this solution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/131108/how-to-use-the-split-function-in-google-spreadsheets-with-different-delimiters-a) but it does not allow for an if / or possibility.

Any help is much appreciated <3

Answer (score 0):

You can use REGEXREPLACE, like this:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\b(on|to|for)\b","/")
```

Comment: thank you so much! @ztiaa!